# Crystal Reports to SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports

I've been using CR for about 2 years now, but I'd like to begin to port some of the reports I've developed in CR over to SSRS.

Anyone know of any guides or how-to's on getting used to designing in SSRS vs. CR?  I'm using Visual Studio 2012, with the Business Intelligence Report Services template.

Just a totally different look than I'm used to.

Comment: You may want to check [SoftwareRecs.SE](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), be sure to check the FAQ there though, you need to change up your question for it to be on topic there.

Comment: Thanks, forgot to change forums.

Comment: Its very hard task because two reports have very different architecture. There are some sites claiming conversion but trust me you need to do manual labor at the end. And there are not clear cut rules for conversion.